Who is ??? In Cult of the Lamb?
I met a character called ??? in Cult of the Lamb. They told me they might see me again, depending on how I do (don’t remember the exact words, been a couple days).
How do I see them again? Who are they? And is there a way to get their real name?

According to Cult of the Lamb wiki:
A enigmatic character who made their first appearance after the Relics of the Old Faith update, as a post-game character and vendor, ??? is also dubbed

the "Mystic Seller"


After the Lamb defeats The One Who Waits, ??? will appear in front of the gate that would otherwise lead to the final dungeon.
Additionally, after the Lamb retrieves their first God Tear, ??? will allow the player to give them a name in exchange for a full partnership.

How do I see them again?

Sorry back, thanks
